# Thread stopping using volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically if I remove unnecessary stuff I have this code:

```
public class Foo {
    private volatile boolean isFinished = false;
    private long timeOut = 60 * 1000;
    ...

    // Called asynchronously from another thread
    public setFinished(boolean value) {
        isFinished = value;
    }

    public wait() {
       ...
       long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
       while(!isFinished && (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start) <= timeOut) {
           ...
       }

       if (isFinished) {
           // Log success!!!
           ...
       }
       else {
           // Log time out!!!
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

This code works 95% of the time. The log file is similar to this:

```
`wait()` is called waiting starts
`setFinished(true)` is called
`setFinished(true)` returns
"success" entry in the log
```

But sometimes, according to log file the following happens:

```
`wait()` is called waiting starts
`setFinished(true)` is called
`setFinished(true)` returns
about 60 seconds pass
"time out" entry in the log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Presuambly that should be `if (isFinished)` and note `value` is an unused argument in `setFinished()`.

Comment: @hmjd yes, fixed that. Original code doesn't have that problem.

Comment: And what about the `if` condition?

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (isFinished)`?

Comment: @Caner This is indeed wrong here: "if (!isFinished)", it should be "if (isFinished)". So then, you cannot make too many conclusions based on your log file.

Comment: I think your naming is confusing `isFinished` should be `isCancelled`

Comment: Sorry about `isFinished` confusion. It is indeed `if (isFinished)` in the original code. Fixed taht now.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that there is something inside these three points which blocks the loop execution:

```
while(!isFinished && (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start) <= timeOut) {
       ...
}
```

Update: you might also try using `System.currentTimeMillis()` as `uptimeMillis()` clock can stop due to changes in environment.

Comment: Yes, that could be it. I have some code that uses `MessageQueue`/`Looper` inside while loop. Can you explain how this effects memory read?

Comment: It very much depends on how you use the queue. If `MessageQueue` can block execution, it might be it. You could try printing time labels inside this loop to make sure there are enough timeout checks made.

Comment: there are times execution is totally stopped inside the while loop. But still after while loop exits with timeout `isFinished` should be `true` and time out should not be printed in the logs.

Comment: Yes, it must be `true`, I can't say how it could become `false` unless it was reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

If `isFinished` only ever transitions from false to true, AND if the while loop has exited, THEN `isFinished` just has to be true.

This would be the case even if you didn't specify `volatile` (in practice), and it would definitely be the case given that you specified `volatile` (both in theory and in practice).

Therefore my guess is that the first assumption is false. If I were you, I'll try this:

```
// Called asynchronously from another thread
public setFinished(boolean value) {
    if(!value){
        throw new AssertionError("huh?");
    }
    isFinished = value;
}
```

and see what happens.